# Running grunt on windows 8

Tags: windows, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I am trying to run grunt on an existing project on a windows 8 machine.
I've installed grunt-cli globally,by running:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

However when trying to run the project with:

```
grunt develop
```

I get this error:

```
Warning: Unable to write "preview.html" file <Error code: EPERM>. Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
```

Then when running

```
grunt develop --force
```

I get this error:

```
Running "less:css/main.css" <less> task
Fatal error: Unable to write "css/main.css" file <Error code: EPERM>.
```

Any help you could provide on this would be most helpful, 
thanks.

### Update 1:

This is my Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

  grunt.initConfig({
    watch: {
      less: {
        files: ['**/*.less', '!less/_compiled-main.less'],
        tasks: 'less'
    },
    html: {
        files: ['preview-template.html', 'js/**/*.js', 'less/**/*.less', '!less/_compiled-main.less'],
        tasks: ['includeSource', 'add-dont-edit-prefix-to-preview-html']
    },
    wysiwyg: {
        files: ['less/wysiwyg.less'],
        tasks: 'generate-wysiwyg-styles-js'
    }
},
less: {
  'css/main.css': 'less/_compiled-main.less',
  'css/wysiwyg.css': 'less/wysiwyg.less',
  options: {
    dumpLineNumbers: 'comments'
}
},
includeSource: {
  options: {
    templates: {

    },
},
dev: {
    files: {
      'preview.html': 'preview-template.html',
      'less/_compiled-main.less': 'less/main.less'
  }
}
},
connect: {
  server: {
    options: {
      base: '.',
      port: 8000
  }
}
}
});

  // Css preprocessor
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
  // Watch for file changes and run other grunt tasks on change
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  // Includes all js files in preview-template.html and saves as preview.html.
  // Includes all less files in main.less and saves as _compiled-main.less
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-include-source');
  // Static http server
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');

  grunt.registerTask('generate-wysiwyg-styles-js', function(){
    var css = grunt.file.read('css/wysiwyg.css');
    css = css.replace(/\n/g, '')
    var js = '// This file is generated automatically based on wysiwyg.less - don\' edit it directly!\n';
    js += '// It needs to exist in JS form so we can include the CSS in the downloaded saved notes file';
    js += "\napp.value('wysiwygStyles', '" + css + "');";
    grunt.file.write('js/app/wysiwyg-styles.js', js)
})

  grunt.registerTask('add-dont-edit-prefix-to-preview-html', function(){
    var file = grunt.file.read('preview.html');
    var prefix = '<!-- \n\n\n\n Don\'t edit this file, edit preview-template.html instead.' + new Array(20).join('\n') + ' -->';
    file = file.replace('<!doctype html>', '<!doctype html>' + prefix)
    grunt.file.write('preview.html', file);
});

  grunt.registerTask('build-develop', [
    'includeSource',
    'less',
    'generate-wysiwyg-styles-js',
    'add-dont-edit-prefix-to-preview-html'
    ])

  grunt.registerTask('develop', [
    'build-develop',
    'connect:server',
    'watch'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: the problem is in your gruntfile, not the `grunt` utility, if you post the file contents I may be able to help you

Comment: thanks, just posted Gruntfile.js as an update to the questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this maybe?

```
less: {
  files: {
    'css/main.css': 'less/_compiled-main.less',
    'css/wysiwyg.css': 'less/wysiwyg.less'
  },
  options: {
    dumpLineNumbers: 'comments'
  }
}
```

Notice the `files` addition to the less array after `grunt.initConfig`

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your help, finally figured out the issue. The folder it was running in was read only!